# Bluetooth MIDI - Windows

Tags: windows, bluetooth, driver, midi

I am trying to connect a Bluetooth Low Energy enabled MIDI hardware to wirelessly send data to a Windows PC and get it to detect as a MIDI device in Windows. Currently, the device is able to pair with my Windows 10 laptop and I am able to read the incoming data off of it.

The same hardware is configured and working fine as a wireless MIDI device on Mac and iOS devices(which natively supports MIDI over Bluetooth). I am trying to get this feature implemented on Windows(which doesn't support MIDI over Bluetooth, although it was promised in Windows 10).

The device, when is paired, is showing up in the 'Bluetooth devices' section in device manager, I am trying to make this device showing up as a MIDI device in 'Sound, video and game controllers' section.
Any help/resources somebody can provide to help me crack this problem is highly appreciated.

Following is my current thought process to implement this.

1. Pair the device and read the data off of it. (Already implemented)
2. Create a virtual MIDI port. (Don't know how to implement this, I am currently checking out [rtpMIDI](http://www.tobias-erichsen.de/software/rtpmidi.html))
3. Send the MIDI data which was read from the BLE device to the virtual MIDI port. (Still don't know how to implement this)

Any suggestions/comments on the above thought process as I am absolutely new to Windows Driver Development.

Comment: I've heard from reliable sources that MIDI over Bluetooth is coming to Win10 very soon; quite possibly in the next update. Might be worth to wait a bit rather than banging your head on the desk trying to deal with the virtual MIDI port mess.

Comment: Hopefully soon, because I am have major issues implementing the above and there is significant latency too.

Comment: @dev_000 I'm trying to do the same thing and need to stay with Win7. Could you share your existing code somewhere like GitHub, maybe even just a gist? Or point us to a good source for reading the data stream? Thanks!